# show error message next to input field

Tags: php, html

I would like to display php error message next to the input field..how can I do that?

Here is my php and html code on a same page..It is just simple test code.. any help would be great

Tried putting the php next to input but that didn't work..instead I put it in a value

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");


$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

if (empty($henny)) { $errorhenny = '<div class="isa_error">Frist name is required<br></div>'; } 

if (empty($lname)) {
echo '<div class="isa_error">Last name is required<br></div>';
}

else{

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fname, $lname);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
}
}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" value= "<?php echo $errorhenny; ?>">
<input type="text" name="lname">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: if (empty($fname)) {
$errorfname=  '<div class="isa_error">Frist name is required<br></div>';
} then print it next to the input <?php echo $errorfname; ?>

Comment: it says undefined variable

Comment: post your new code (update your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$ferr = '';
$lerr = '';
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");


$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

if (empty($fname)) {
$ferr = 'First name is required';
}

if (empty($lname)) {
$lerr = 'Last name is required';
}

else{

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (?, ?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fname, $lname);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
}
}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <span class="isa_error"><?php echo $ferr;?></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <span class="isa_error"><?php echo $lerr;?></span>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any way that I can prevent the class isa error showing on the page before the error message get displayed. I mean like when the page loads the css shows first, prior to hittin submit..Can I make the css only show when the error is displayed?

Comment: You can set the `isa_errorf` class to `display:none` using CSS and show it only when there is an error. Let me know if you have any trouble doing it.

Comment: I'm having trouble...I put display:none; and nothing comes on when the error occurs...

Comment: Can you post your complete code in a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and post the link so that i can see/modify it.

Comment: thanks I got it work by putting the class in the php code and changing the div to span...

Answer (score 0):

try using ajax... much easier and nicer

Answer (score 0):

Assign the error message in php variable,

```
if (empty($fname)) { 
     $errorfname= '<div class="isa_error">Frist name is required</div>'; 
} 
if (empty($lname)) { 
     $errorlname = '<div class="isa_error">Last name is required</div>'; 
}
```

then print the variable in html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname">
<?php if(isset($errorfname)) { echo $errorfname; } ?> // fname error message
<input type="text" name="lname">
 <?php if(isset($errorlname)) { echo $errorlname; } ?> //lname error message
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");


  $fname = $_POST["fname"];
  $lname = $_POST["lname"];
  if(empty($fname) || empty($lname)){
    if (empty($fname)) { 
       $errorfname = '<div class="isa_error">Frist name is required<br></div>'; 
    } 

    if (empty($lname)) {
       $errorlastname = '<div class="isa_error">Last name is required<br></div>';
    }
  }
  else{

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $fname, $lname);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->close();
  }
}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" value= ""><?php echo isset($errorfname) ? $errorfname : ''; ?>
<input type="text" name="lname"><?php echo isset($errorlastname) ? $errorlastname : ''; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```